# Converting a UTC time string to Unix time

Tags: mysql, convert-tz

In my database, I'm storing time as a BIGINT UTC value.

In my test data SQL dump I'd like to see the time in UTC for readability. However, the MySQL unix_timestamp function expects time in the local time zone, which I'm trying to avoid.

I've looked around and the only way I've found of converting the UTC time string to a unix time stamp is using this expression:

`SELECT unix_timestamp(CONVERT_TZ('2011-08-08 06:00:00','UTC',@@global.time_zone))`

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stored it as a timestamp instead of a bigint it would happen automatically just by setting the timezone.

Also, I don't really understand what you are doing. You are storing unixtime as your bigint column correct? So I don't get why you are using the `unix_timestamp()` function - that converts TO a unixtime, not from it.

I guess this is what you need:

```
SET time_zone = '+0:00';
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(col) FROM table;
```

Comment: My data comes in as Unix timestamps and goes out as Unix timestamps so it makes sense to store it as a BIGINT. The reason why I use unix_timestamp is so that I can read the dates that go into the database. Otherwise my test data is littered with unix timestamps I can't easily read.

Comment: No it doesn't. It makes sense to store it as timestamps. unix_timestamp converts *TO* a unix time (a number). Do you mean `from_unixtime()`? Because all you have to do is set the current timezone to utc and it will just work. And on top of that timestamps automatically convert to human readable dates. (You select them +0 to convert them to numbers.)

Comment: Still, we're storing them as numbers now and this isn't going to change. In my test code however, I want to see them as UTC date/time strings. Do you have any idea how to do this conversion (without setting UTC in the database -- I don't have any control over that)

Comment: SET time_zone = '+0:00'; SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(col) ....; This will only affect the current connection, it does not change the database.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that this was per-connection. Just what I needed. Thanks!